# Given constants $c_i$ and $K$, find $b$ numerically such that $b^{c_1} + b^{c_2} + \dots + b^{c_n} = K$

Tags: numerical-methods

Given constants $c_i > 0$ and $K > 0$, find $b > 0$ numerically such that $b^{c_1} + b^{c_2} + \dots + b^{c_n} = K$. I'd like to solve this with a non-iterative method if possible.

My attempt at isolating b (applying the identity $\log(x + y) = \log x + \log(1 + y/x)$):

$$K = b^{c_1} + b^{c_2} + \dots$$
$$\log(K) = \log(b^{c_1} + b^{c_2} + \dots)$$
$$\log(K) = c_1 \log(b) + \log(1 + b^{c_2-c_1} + b^{c_3-c_1} + \dots)$$
$$\log(K) = c_1 \log(b) + \log(1 + b^{c_2-c_1}) + \log(1 + \frac{b^{c_3-c_1}}{(1 + b^{c_2-c_1})} + \dots)$$
$$\log(K) = c_1 \log(b) + \log(1 + b^{c_2-c_1}) + \log(1 + \frac{b^{c_3-c_1}}{(1 + b^{c_2-c_1})}) + \log(1 + \dots)$$

It doesn't appear to lead anywhere clean where I can isolate $b$ and use the log1p function. Any ideas?

Comment: If $K>n$, then $1<b<(K-n+1)^{1/({\rm max}c_i)}$. If $K < n$, then $(K/n)^{{1/({\rm min}c_i)}}<b<1$

Answer (score 1):

*I shall admit that the* $c_i$ *are sorted by increasing order*.

For the most general case, you will need an iterative method to find the zero of the equation
$$f(b)=\sum_{i=1}^n b^{c_i} -K$$ Since $f(b)$ may vary very fast, it is better (as you did) to consider instead the function
$$g(b)=\log\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b^{c_i} \right)-\log(K)$$ for which
$$g'(b)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\,b^{c_i-1} } {\sum_{i=1}^n b^{c_i} }$$

In comments, @Ivan Kaznacheyeu gave bounds for the variable. So, take the midpoint and start Newton method or, if you are as lazy as I am, start with $b_0=1$.

For illustration, take $n=10$,  let $c_i$ be the first prime numbers and $K=10^{15}$. So, the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & b_n \\
 0 & 1.00000 \\
 1 & 3.49893 \\
 2 & 3.28378 \\
 3 & 3.29025
\end{array}
\right)$$